# Wrong TStatfs record on Mac OS loaded

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I have installed fpc 3.2.2 and Lazarus IDE v 2.2.2 on MAC macOS Catalina 10.15.7

I am trying to use record

```
{$if defined(cpuarm) or defined(cpuaarch64) or defined(iphonesim)}
 { structure used on iPhoneOS and available on Mac OS X 10.6 and later }
 tstatfs = record
      bsize : cuint32;
      iosize : cint32;
      blocks : cuint64;
      bfree : cuint64;
      bavail : cuint64;
      files : cuint64;
      ffree : cuint64;
      fsid : fsid_t;
      owner : uid_t;
      ftype : cuint32;
      fflags : cuint32;
      fssubtype : cuint32;
      fstypename : array[0..(MFSNAMELEN)-1] of char;
      mountpoint : array[0..(PATH_MAX)-1] of char;
      mntfromname : array[0..(PATH_MAX)-1] of char;
      reserved: array[0..7] of cuint32;
 end;
{$else}
     tstatfs = record
          otype : cint16;
          oflags : cint16;
          bsize : clong;
          iosize : clong;
          blocks : clong;
          bfree : clong;
          bavail : clong;
          files : clong;
          ffree : clong;
          fsid : fsid_t;
          fowner : uid_t;
          reserved1 : cint16;
          ftype : cint16;
          fflags : clong;
          reserved2 : array[0..1] of clong;
          fstypename : array[0..(MFSNAMELEN)-1] of char;
          mountpoint : array[0..(MNAMELEN)-1] of char;
          mntfromname : array[0..(MNAMELEN)-1] of char;
          f_reserved3: char;
          reserved4: array[0..3] of clong;
       end;
{$endif}
    pstatfs = ^tstatfs;
```

but the record is loaded wrong, from the {$else} part.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance
Bojan

Comment: You say: *but the record is loaded wrong, from the {$else} part.* In what way is it loaded wrong? You do know that the structure describes 2 *alternative* record structures. On 10.15.7 you should be concerned with the first structure only as that is used on 10.6 and later. Sorry, if I speak rubbish, I'm not a macOS developer.

Comment: You may also want to check your `$A` or `$ALIGN` settings.

Comment: I agree with you. Old stat(fs) record are included in the newer MAC version. But, as you can see using first structure (record), depends on processor type. If I define cpuaarch64, application is build, but in execution it says something like "upgrade to version 11...".